# How to differentiate identifier from function call in LL(1) parser

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

My graduate student and I are working on a training compiler, which we will use to teach students at the subject "Compilers and Interpreters".
The input program language is a limited subset of the Java language and the compiler implementation language is Java.

The grammar of the input language syntax is LL(1), because it is easier to be understood and implemented by students. We have the following general problem in the parser implementation. How to differentiate identifier from function call during the parsing?

For example we may have:

```
b = sum(10,5) //sum is a function call
```

or

```
b = a //a is an identifier
```

In both cases after the `=` symbol we have an identifier.
Is it possible to differentiate what kind of construct (a function call or an identifier) we have after the equality symbol `=`?

May be it is not possible in LL(1) parser, as we can look only 1 symbol ahead? If this is true, how do you recommend to define the function call in the grammar? Maybe some additional symbol in front of the function call is necessary, e.g. `b = @sum(10,5)`?

Do You think this symbol would be confusing for students? What kind of symbol for the function call would be proper?

Comment: This is completely off-topic and definitely <opinion>: I think generations of students (myself included) have been very badly served by PL courses which start with syntax and only get around to the good stuff in a rush at the end or even not until the next year. I'd be inclined to give my students a functional parser which returns an AST and dive straight into the equivalent of SICP. What does it mean? How do we implement its meaning? How do we represent its meaning? Later (maybe in the second year) we could look at syntax as a UI issue, and only then think about how to implement the parser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You indeed can't have separate rules for function calls and variables in an LL(1) grammar because that would require additional lookahead. The common solution to this is to combine them into one rule that matches an identifier, optionally followed by an argument list:

```
primary_expression ::= ID ( "(" expression_list ")" )?
                     | ...
```

In a language where a function can be an arbitrary expression, not just an identifier, you'll want to treat it just like any other postfix operator:

```
postfix_expression ::= primary_expression postfix_operator*

postfix_operator ::= "++"
                   | "--"
                   | "[" expression "]"
                   | "(" expression_list ")"
```

Comment: Great answer. I'd even go as far as to recommend the postfix operator method, because (at least in Java) an identifier isn't the only receiver of function call: you can invoke methods: `b = a.getD();` You can even invoke methods on return values: `b = a.getD().getD().getD().getD().getD()....;`

Comment: @JacobKrall The Java grammar actually has separate rules for `a.b()` and `a()`. The former is covered by a rule that basically defines `"." ID ("(" expression_list ")")?` as a postfix operator ("selector", actually) and the former by a rule like the first code snippet in my answer.

Comment: What happens if you write `(a).b();`?

Comment: @JacobKrall Then `(a)` is a primary expression and `.b()` is a selector, so `(a).b()` matches the `primary selector*` rule (and `(a).b();` then matches `ExpressionStatement`). What you can't match is `(a)()`, but that's actually by design. Basically the Java grammar enforces that the token directly before the opening parenthesis of the argument list must be an identifier. This wouldn't work in languages that allow functions as values, but Java doesn't, so it can do things this way.

Comment: I’m veering pretty far off topic, but why isn’t that allowed in Java 8? What about lambda expressions and method references? Do you always have to store those in a parameter or variable before invoking them?

Comment: If function calls are treated as general postfix operators where the operand could be parenthesized then casts become ambiguous. Of course, you might not care about the ambiguity (eg. C) or you might not allow casts, or you might accept that cast expressions require your grammar to jump through hoops (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-UnaryExpressionNotPlusMinus)

Comment: @JacobKrall You can't call lambdas as if they were methods. You'll have to call them as `myLambda.apply(arguments)` (or using a different method name depending on the type of `myLambda`).

Comment: @rici Good point. If `(f)(x)` is a legal function call, the ambiguity exists (regardless of how I structure the grammar to make this possible, so it's not like I can just restructure the grammar to fix this - I have to actually change the language - nor do I think there's a nice way to allow `fs[i](x)`, but not `(fs[i])(x)` and still keep the grammar LL(k)). At least as long as `(T)(x)` is also valid syntax for a cast. Personally I'd rather change the syntax for casts (or get rid of them altogether, as you say) than for function calls if I wanted to avoid this problem.

Comment: @sepp2k. Me, too, although I'm not fond of `static_cast<long>(j)` either. I've always favoured `j as long`.